# ReportViewer não exibe valor do objeto?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando gerar um relatório com o ReportViewer sobre os itens de uma venda, o relatório é exibido mas na coluna de produtos ao invés de aparecer o produto aparece `#Erro`. Minhas classes estão todas com `[Serializable]` mas mesmo assim não está funcionando e retorna o warning: `Warning: A expressão Value para textrun ‘produto.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contém um erro: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)`.

O mais estranho é que se eu der um `foreach` na lista antes de gerar o relatório as informações são exibidas no `Console` e tbm no ReportViewer corretamente. Mas passando a lista diretamente sem o `foreach` nao funciona.

Como resolver esse problema ?

Gerando relatório.

```
private void geraRelContasReceberDetalhado() {
            foreach (ItemVenda iv in this.listaItens) {
                Console.WriteLine("produto: " + iv.produto.descricao);
            }
            reportViewer.Reset();
            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"..\..\reports\RelContasReceberDetalhado.rdlc";
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetRelContasReceberDetalhado", this.listaItens);
            //List<ReportParameter> listParams = new List<ReportParameter>();                
            // rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(listParams);
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        }
```

**Classes**

```
//ItemVenda
[Serializable]
    public class ItemVenda {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }
        public virtual Venda venda                  { set; get; }
        public virtual Produto produto              { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorUn              { set; get; }
        public virtual int quantidade               { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal total                { set; get; }

        public ItemVenda() {            
        }
    }


[Serializable]
    public class Produto {

        public virtual long id                              { set; get; }        
        public virtual string descricao                     { set; get; }
        public virtual CategoriaProduto categoriaProduto    { set; get; }
        public virtual UnidadeProduto unidadeProduto        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorCusto                   { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorVenda                   { set; get; }
        public virtual int qtdEstoque                       { set; get; }
        public virtual int estoqueMin                       { set; get; }
        public virtual int estoqueMax                       { set; get; }
        public virtual int status                           { set; get; }
        public virtual string imagem                        { set; get; }

        public Produto() {            
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return descricao;
        }

    }
```

Print do relatório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa lista vem do ORM Entity Framework?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estou usando o NHibernate com FluentNHibernate.

Comment: Faz uma linq e traz esses itens formatados fica melhor ou faz um query com join.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou tentar !

Comment: Você conseguiu @FernandoPaiva?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não, então mantive o foreach antes de invocar o relatorio e assim uma gambiarra que funciona.

Comment: coloque na pergunta da onde resulta a variável this.listaItens. Vou ver e te respondo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ela eh um `IList<ItemVenda>` que passo como DataSet para o report. O mais estranho é como falei, se passo ela sem fazer o `foreach` antes ela não exibe a descricao do produto que está em seu mapeamento. Tenho outros relatórios que passo tbm um `IList` como DataSet e nao tenho esse problema, apenas nessa lista de item que deu isso. E todas as minhas classes estao com `[Serializable]` por isso nem tenho ideia do que possa ser. Obrigado.

Comment: Ok, coloque as linhas que carregam essa lista